# How to dynamically prepend classname to the element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given I have an element with some classes, I want to add additional class to it. But it shouldn't overwrite the existing styles applied by existing classes if any.

So for example if I apply style color in the class "green", it applies only to the element where color is not defined already by class, (bonus defined by inline style)

`<div class="red">` becomes `<div class="green red">`, should still be red, since the last class applied.

I tried using className prepend class with javascript, but it strangely didn't work for me.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".elements");
elements.forEach(el => el.className = "green " + el.className);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="elements red">I am still red</div>
    <div class="elements"> I am green now</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What you've written should work. But it's better to use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) rather than `className`.

Comment: When I run your code, both are green. Note that when you add `green` you don't remove `red`. The last match in the CSS takes precedence.

Comment: The order of classes in the `class=` attribute is not significant, there's no difference between `class="red green"` and `class="green red"`. What matters is the order in the `<style>`

Comment: If you don't want the new style to overwrite the old one, the best option is remove the old one. That way you ensure it works and don't have to mess with the order of the styles, using !important or any other weird hack.

Comment: So `el.classList.remove("red"); el.classList.add("green");`

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar says in the comments the order of the classes is not significant in the application of the styles but matter the order in the style tag (or file).

If you want your element to still be red you should add !important to your red class.

```
.red {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Or if you want to add the green class only to the elements who aren't already red, you can modify your js script something like this:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("elements");
for (const el of elements) {
    if(!el.classList.contains('red'))
        el.classList.add('green')
}
```